# Help me figure out what kind of bike I'm riding

Tags: bmx

What kind of bike is this based off this logo[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  This is a very blurry photo; do you have any other information?

Comment: If you could get a less blurry photo it should be possible to cut out the image of the logo and use Google image search to get a match.

Comment: Why do you need to know? What is the problem that is solved by knowing the make and model?

Comment: They only ask about the type of the bike, not the make and model. Based on the facts that it's posted on bicycles.se and doesn't have any good photos, I think all the chances are that it's a BMX.

Comment: In addition to an in-focus photo, a shot showing the entire bicycle would help.

Answer (score 3):

That is the Premium Products logo

[image]

Here is the logo on a crank
[image]

Here is a link to the [Premium Products BMX bikes in the BMX Museum](https://bmxmuseum.com/bikes/premium_products/)

Comment: On balance, does this imply the whole frame is from "premium products" or just the rear dropout?  One might presume that their name would be more obvious on the frame if it were the whole thing ?

Comment: @Criggie based on the picture that was given the only thing I'm willing to say for sure is that the logo is Premium Products.